# Can I choose a Cloud Kernel Version to run my code? (DatePlus broken case)

Tags: date-and-time, wolfram-cloud, cloud-deploy

One of my APIs suddenly broke, and I discovered that if I evaluate

```
   Block[{$DateStringFormat = "ISODateTime"},
    DatePlus["2021-09-20", 1]
   ]
```

In my Desktop I get:

```
 "2021-09-21T00:00:00"
```

In Wolfram Cloud I get:

```
cannot be interpreted as a date or time input or as a date string format
```

Small question: It's a bug in this release? Or a compatibility change?

Big Question: Can I choose my cloud version, to avoid this kind of broke?

Notes

- In my desktop I have the \$Version = "12.3.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (May 10, 2021)"
- In Wolfram Cloud \$Version = "12.3.1 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (June 24, 2021)"

Comment: I would guess the answer to the edited question title to be "No".  I don't reproduce when I evaluate on the cloud: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7B7gT.png

Comment: @JasonB. I messed the `$DateStringFormat` line. Can you check again?

Comment: In that case, I get the same error in desktop 12.3.1 as I do in the cloud.

Comment: As a workaround you can create an intermediate `DateObject` via `DateString[DatePlus[DateObject["2021-09-20"], 1], "ISODateTime"]`

Comment: @JasonB. The major problem is that I can't have control over the version my code is running. So it's very easy to have a compatibility break, like this case. The my API just stoped

Comment: Looks like it was a bug and is fixed in the next release. As a workaround you can use `{"ISODateTIme"}` instead of just the string `"ISODateTime"`.